# Race Condition for Shell Blocks in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

> Update: This behavior is observed on Windows Subsystem for Linux. It seems there are two issues we are dealing with here:
>
> 1. <s>Some bug/race condition internal to the system.</s> This is incorrect, see answers.
> 2. Default buffer size for `head`.
>
> For (2), as @kusalanda mentioned, `head` may have some default buffer size that consumes the input up to a certain point. On ArchLinux, we can see that for `i < 10`, we consistently see no output from `tail`. The same is true for Windows Subsystem for Linux (i.e. no inconsistent output for `tail`).
>   <s>For (1), it is possible that there is some bug internal to the Windows Subsystem for Linux itself that causes this race condition, as we do not observe such behavior in ArchLinux.</s> This is incorrect, see answers. There is a "point 1", but it is different.

I am trying to run the following commands in `bash` version `4.4.19`:

```
{ for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
```

Sometimes, I see the expected results:

```
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
999
$ ~
```

However, more often than not, I see the following:

```
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
$ ~
```

I suspect this is a race condition. However, if I add a sleep at the beginning of the second block of commands, the "race condition" still happens:

```
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { sleep 10; head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
$ ~
```

Is this actually a race condition? What should I do to make the second block of code see the whole input? Note that if I use `10000` instead of `1000`, then I do not see this issue (it is possible that these all just happen to be lucky cases though):

```
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
9999
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
9999
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
9999
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
9999
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
9999
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)); do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
9999
$ ~
```

Comment: What Unix are you on? On some Unices, the `head` implementation buffers too much of the input data and leaves nothing for `tail` to work on (this is an error). This ought to be deterministic though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see this with `i < 1000` on Windows Subsystem for Linux, and `i < 10` for ArchLinux. Now that you mention it, this might be a Windows Subsystem for Linux issue (with regards to the non-determinism). For ArchLinux, at least so far, the behavior seems deterministic. I will update the question with this information.

Comment: WSL is not Linux....it emulates a Linux environment for all purposes, on top of the Windows HAL. Hmmmm...I wonder.where is Ipor Sircer and his "File a bug report".

Comment: @Kusalananda this doesn't have to be deterministic (unless you mean it in a philosophical sense). In a pipeline like `foo | bar`, how much a read(2) inside `bar` will return is dependent not only on how much `foo` is writing into the pipe, but also on how the kernel schedules the `foo` and `bar` processes to run. Notice that pipes on Unix are not message/boundary preserving; 5 writes in `foo` may result in a single read in `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

This is no race condition and **no bug** in WSL or ArchLinux.

As you mention, it's because `head` is reading more than it "should", and so it may not leave enough or anything at all for `tail` to work on. But there is nothing in the standard or elsewhere which says that `head` should only read a certain amount of bytes; it could just as well read the whole file and then discard everything but its first line.

In order to "fix" that in all possible cases, `head` would have to always read its input byte by byte (ie do a system call for each byte) and that would be horrendously inefficient, and absolutely useless in 99.999% of cases.

If you want to avoid that, you can

1) use a temporary file instead of a pipe; then

```
{ head -n 2 <tmpfile; tail -n 3 <tmpfile; }
```

will work as expected.

2) reimplement your head/tail combination with something else, eg. in `awk`:

```
$ seq 10000 20000 | awk -vH=2 -vT=3 '{if(NR<=H)print; else a[i++%T]=$0}END{if((j=i-T)>0)print "..."; else j=0; while(j<i)print a[j++%T]}'
10000
10001
...
19998
19999
20000
```

Comment: I see, but can you explain in more detail the reason for the inconsistent behavior? Even in case of `foo | bar` where `foo` and `bar` executes at different schedules each time we run it, wouldn't the output of `bar` still be the same, provided `bar` itself is "deterministic"? I mean regardless of how the kernel schedules it, at least in the case of `head` and `tail`, would the output not always be the same given the same input, albeit with different buffered reads?

Comment: Keep in mind that if `bar` does eg. a `read(0, buf, 4096)`, the kernel will NOT wait until 4096 bytes have accumulated in the pipe buffer but will just return whatever is already there. But that depends on how much `foo` was able to write, which in turn depends on the load of the system, on how the kernel decided to interspede the executions of `foo`, `bar` and all the other processes, handle interrupt storms, user input, etc. As I already said in another comment, a single write may result in multiple reads and multiple writes in a single read.

Comment: @nehcsivart: You can quasi-observe the scheduling issue by delaying the *left*-hand side of the pipe - just put a tiny `sleep` into each iteration - and see that it behaves consistently then. It's no more correct either way, though, on `head`'s part or the system's. Regardless, any time (descendents of) the same file handle are accessed from multiple processes you're well into the woods: POSIX [says that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01) "It is implementation-defined whether, and under what conditions, all input is seen exactly once.".

Comment: @MichaelHomer @mosvy Thanks, I think I understand now. Long story short, suppose `head` will consume input of 1000 (which it probably does). If all of the left side finishes before the right side even starts, `head` will consume everything, leaving nothing for `tail`. If, however, the left side does not finish, `head` will only consume those that are done. This means something is leftover for `tail`. I will add an answer that explains this experimentally in more detail. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

*Note: If any information is incorrect, please comment so I can fix or delete.*

As @mosvy and @MichaelHomer mentioned in the comments, this is due to the scheduler scheduling each side of the pipe differently, and at different times. To be clear, we are answering why the following has inconsistent output:

```
{ for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done } | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
```

With output like:

```
0
...
```

and:

```
0
...
999
```

Two key points are at play here. The short answer is that because the input into the right side of the pipe is not always all available at once (point 1), `head` will "consume" different amounts. If the whole input is available (meaning the left side finished first), then the whole input will be consumed due to the implementation of `head` as explained by @Kusalananda and @mosvy (point 2).

We will first show point 1. The easiest way to show this is to replace `tail` with `head`:

```
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done } | { head -n 1; echo ...; head -n 1; }
0
...
878
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done } | { head -n 1; echo ...; head -n 1; }
0
...
820
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done } | { head -n 1; echo ...; head -n 1; }
0
...
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done } | { head -n 1; echo ...; head -n 1; }
0
...
796
```

As we can see, the output of the second `head` is different each time. This shows that the input from the left side is not always available all at once (point 1).

For each of the case in which there is a number after `...`, we will get an output of `999` if we used `tail` instead. For the case in which nothing came after `...`, we will see the same for `tail`. To prove this, we will show point 2.

Although there is nothing we can really do about point 1, we *can* make it more stable by writing it to a file:

```
$ ~ { for ((i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)); do echo $i; done } >input
```

With the file, we will read it through a pipe (see below for redirection case):

```
$ ~ cat input | { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; }
0
...
```

And indeed, `head` consumes everything, leaving nothing for `tail`. As such, we have point 2. So with point 1 and point 2, we can explain the inconsistent behavior:

> In my version of `head`, at least 1000 lines will be consumed at a time if read through a pipe, and at least 1000 lines are available (the whole thing if less). If all of the left side finishes before the right side even starts, `head` will consume everything, leaving nothing for `tail`. If, however, the left side does not finish, `head` will only consume those that are done. This means something is leftover for `tail`, thus leaving an output.

### Redirection

So in the above example, we used a pipe to provide the result. The reasoning is that if we used redirection, we will end up with the following result:

```
$ ~ { head -n 1; echo ...; tail -n 1; } <input
0
...
999
```

Which is different from the explanation above. The reasoning is that when used this way, it seems `head` only reads 1 line:

```
$ ~ { head -n 1; echo ...; head -n 1; } <input
0
...
1
```

The way to explain this is to reference the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074550). In short:

> - pipes are not lseek()'able so commands can't read some data and then rewind back, but when you redirect with > or < usually it's a file which is lseek() able object, so commands can navigate however they please.

In other words, `head` need not consume everything if it is able to seek the file directly. It only need to read as much as it need. Once it finds a newline, it can put everything back. We can prove this by using a file with 1 byte after a newline:

```
$ ~ cat input
0123456789
1
$ ~ { head -n 1; head -c 1; } <input
0123456789
1$ ~
```

If we were to use a pipe, the whole input is consumed, with nothing left for the second `head`:

```
$ ~ cat input | { head -n 1; head -c 1; }
0123456789
$ ~
```

As a side note, if we used process substitution (which results in a non-seekable read as I understand it), we will get the same result:

```
$ ~ { head -n 1; head -c 1; } < <(cat input)
0123456789
$ ~
```